How are line breaks determined by the Text view in SwiftUI and can I manipulate this behaviour?
Im interested in knowing how Text decides where to put line breaks for text that can't fit in a single line. Take for example this:

This simply wraps text to the next line. Now notice what happens when I put a "/" somewhere in the middle:

It prioritises breaking the line right after the "/"! The same thing happens if I choose to put a "|" somewhere in the middle.
I'm curious to know how this is calculated/determined since there could be more behaviour like this for characters other than just "/" and "|". I am also curious to know if this can be manipulated in SwiftUI. For example in the first image, can I cause a line break right after ":" instead of wrapping around?
If anyone can shed light on how all of this is calculated or where I can find comprehensive information on the subject please do let me know. Additionally, if you know how to manipulate this behaviour in SwiftUI let me know.

See also How to prevent SwiftUI from adding additional hyphen characters inside text?, which relates to word-wrap too

You can manipulate this with TextKit, not SwiftUI though. There is a NSTextLayoutManager delegate method you can implement - shouldBreakLineBefore

@Sweeper before I do a deep dive into TextKit do you know of an existing TextKit method that takes a String as input and then returns something that I can use to determine where line breaks / hyphens have been added? Something akin to runs in attributed string perhaps?

The older NSTextLayoutManager has a enumerateLineFragments method that gives you all the lines. You will need to determine whether each line is caused by an actual newline character or a soft-break.

@Sweeper This work perfectly thank you so much. For those interested, this document was quite useful: Text Layout Programming Guide

It wraps the text at the nearest word. If there is only one word longer than one line, it will continue the word on the next line. It sees a / or - or ? as a new word beginning and it wraps the next line at that break.

Yes but this behaviour is also true for other characters such as "@@" and "$$". I could try guessing but then I'll always feel there is some other rule I haven't stumbled across. Sweepers comment helped me out a lot in case you're interested in the process.

Interesting. Does it only put a line break if the @ or $ is typed twice? Does it display those characters in the text?
